# How To Set Question Mark And Period At End Of Sentences Using SpeechRecognition Web Api?

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to add a question mark to sentences that start with "what" at the beginning of the sentences, but can't think of  away to do it. For everything that is in the sentences, I can simply use:

`if (result.includes(" if")) {               result = result.replace(" if", ", if ");             }`

Maybe one of you can think of another way to use, maybe even the same code, to achieve that objective.

The second problem is in regard to punctuation. I was thinking about setting a period every time the speaker pauses for a few seconds, but would not know how to program this.

*I know there are some libraries and API's, but I chose this way.

Comment: Please list all (or more if too many) cases of substitution

Comment: For the time being, "what" is the only one.

Comment: Yet, your example uses **if** ???

Comment: Please read again. This is for the first problem. For the second problem, I have not had any proper idea on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let speechStr = "what if I don't."

let strsplit = speechStr.split(" ")
for(let i = 0; i < strsplit.length; i++){
  
    if(strsplit[i].toLowerCase() === 'what'){
      
   speechStr = speechStr.slice(0,-1) + '?'
   
}
}

console.log(speechStr)
```

try use the example you talked about to avoid confusion

Comment: I was thinking about something along the lines. If you could wrap yourself about how to add a period at the end of the sentence similarly, I and others, probably too, would appreciate if you could also answer it.